# Windows restart after resuming from sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I put my system to sleep every day but lately, when I resume/open my laptop lid. It starts the windows again and it is a boot all over again.Upon search logs on @Dave way, I found out a critical Kernal-Power which says

> The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This
>   error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or
>   lost power unexpectedly.

I did google but the scenario provided [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2028504/windows-kernel-event-id-41-error-the-system-has-rebooted-without-cleanly-shutting-down-first-in-windows-8.1,-windows-8,-windows-server-2012-r2,-windows-server-2012,-windows-7,-or-windows-server-2008-r2) don't fit me, as I had put my system to sleep.

I looked in yesterday event, when I put my system to sleep and error says

> The previous system shutdown at xx:xx:xx on ‎22/‎06/‎2017 was
>   unexpected.

This is the time, I put my system to sleep.

How can I find which app/service is crashing so I can rectify the problem

Edit: It is worth noting here when it starts the next time, it is really sluggish for good 15-30 minute e.g. I cannot do anything until then.

Comment: Look in the System Event log for anything interesting ...

Comment: We don't either as we can't look at your log. Interesting is errors and startup/restart/shutdown events  and anything happening around the restart time.

Comment: @DavidPostill If you tell me any kind of event/name I should look for then I will be able to tell you

Comment: you can always screenshot your recent event logs and post it here

Comment: @Dave The first entry I se is for critical and soruce is Kernel Power, then a warning for Kernel-PnP, Couple of Error In SCM and DistrinutedCOM , So how do I know what was it.

Comment: If you put your pc to sleep, wait 10 minutes, then fire it up, does it happen then also? And if you wait 1 minute? does it happen then? It is possible your laptop is running out of battery and sleep still requires battery. Consider hibernating instead.

Comment: @LPChip My system is always on plugged in charging. Haven't tired the 10 minutes case.

Comment: @LPChip I tried 10 minutes sleep and 1 minute, It came out of it when I press power button

Comment: Sounds like the power is somehow cut. Can you see if putting the pc into hibernation at the end of the day, and continue the next day works normally? (it should)

Comment: @LPChip I mentioned a new line in the post under Edit. But I will give herniation a try.

Comment: Didn't see the edit. One thing you can try is remove the battery, remove the powercord, and with nothing plugged in, press and hold power for 5 seconds. This will drain every bit of residual energy that could otherwise cause weird problems such as strange slow downs at start and weird BSoD's.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60970/discussion-between-nofel-and-lpchip).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my ASUS ROG GL552VW laptop and it was fixed by re-flashing the BIOS.

To do this, download the latest bios from the manufacturer's website (in my case, [ASUS](https://www.asus.com/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-GL552VW/HelpDesk_Download/)) and a BIOS flashing utility (WinFlash for me)

Run the flashing utility with the BIOS you downloaded.

I also had to run the utility with the `/nodate` command line as the BIOS version was the same (and so the utility would not allow a reflash).
To do this, run > `cmd` > `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\WinFlash` (or similar) > `Winflash /nodate` and the utility starts as normal.